# dataWithContentsOfURL crash when running on iOS8

Tags: ios, iphone, ios8

`dataWithContentsOfURL` crashes on iOS8 when the host is not reachable and there is internet connection.

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:myurl];

    @try {
        data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
    }
    @catch (NSException *exception) {
        data = nil;
    }
    if(data!=nil){
        [data writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
    }else{
        data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
        if (data==nil) {
            return nil;

        }
    }
```

Comment: what's the crash log?

Comment: crash log don't show me any crash

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation:

```
Important: Do not use this synchronous method to request network-based URLs.
For network-based URLs, this method can block the current thread for tens of
seconds on a slow network, resulting in a poor user experience, and in iOS,
may cause your app to be terminated.
```

If you need to know the reason for failure, use **`dataWithContentsOfURL:options:error:`**

Or

Instead, for non-file URLs, consider using the **`dataTaskWithURL:completionHandler:`** method of the NSSession class.